# How to build, deploy and execute dotnet library on Heroku

Tags: heroku, .net-core, github-actions, fluent-migrator

I have .net core 2.1 project library which executes db migrations (using the fluentmigrator). What is the simplest method to to execute this library once I push my code changes (migrations) to github master branch? I was trying to define below yml file and procfile but there is error after the build on release command I have an error:

> /bin/sh: 1: dotnet: not found

How to make possible to build and run .net core app using buildpack. Is it possible without using docker?

```
name: Deploy to Heroku

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./app.db/
    
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.7.8
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: "app-db"
          heroku_email: "myemail"
          buildpack: "https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack"
          appdir: "app.db"
```

Procfile

```
release: cd $HOME/heroku_output && dotnet app.db.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, heroku dyno is a standard ubuntu (18.04 - 20.04 it depends on stack).
Our team used own buildpack and own build script.

HVG/self-buildpack:
https://github.com/HVG/self-buildpack

Sample Asp.Net Core project:
https://gist.github.com/felegy/8834d26063204d129a7b2893a91f6627